# Вопрос-ответная схема предложения, разбор по составу

Tags: синтаксис, подлежащее

```
1. Что хорошо, так это то, что Солженицын перед Западом не пресмыкается.
2. Кто хорош, так это Солженицын.
```

Какое подлежащее и сказуемое в предложениях? Каким членом предложения являются местоимения **что** и **кто**? Второе предложение сложное или простое? Если во втором подлежащее со сказуемым это Кто и Солженицын, то почему между ними запятая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**так это** - указательная частица, а ля **это, вот, вот это**. Проверяется на примерах:

```
Кто хорош - вот это достоевский! 
Что хорошо - (это) то, что достоевский перед западом не пресмыкается 
Чем он вкусен - (это) тем, что он соленый.
```

В [АГ-1980, § 2921](https://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5315&0a0=1828) говорится, что оборот **что/кто ... -/так это/это** выходит за рамки простой контаминации двух разных синтаксических моделей.

> С употреблением придаточного предложения в позиции вводности создаются условия для конструктивного взаимодействия изъяснительной относительной связи со связью союзной и вопросительной. Взаимодействие обнаруживается в обороте типа что... [так это то,] что, **который** **выходит за рамки простой контаминации двух разных синтаксических моделей**, так как специализировался в качестве актуализирующего средства.
>
> Нет, этого я никак не понимаю, решительно не понимаю! Но что страннее,
> что непонятнее всего, это то, как авторы могут брать подобные сюжеты
> (Гоголь); Но что всего вернее, как дважды два, это то, что Лебедев
> обожает и своего племянника (Дост.); Уходя, она прибавила, что
> Лизавета Прокофьевна сегодня в адском расположении духа, но что всего
> страннее, что Аглая перессорилась со всем семейством (Дост.); Одно, на
> что имел право муж, это было на то, чтобы потребовать удовлетворения с
> оружием в руках (Л. Толст.).

Так что синтаксису этого оборота, наверняка, должна быть посвящена куча статей. Он является некоего рода исключительным.

Comment: Дополните пожалуйста: Вид предложения какой?, Значение союз ЧТО? И вид связи: местоименная, союзная? В грамматике не бывает «а ля». Там есть фразеологизированные модели, отнесенные к базовым моделям определенного  вида.

Comment: Вам знакома фразеологизированная модель: "Маша - вот это жена" ? Что тут блин еще дополнять ??? "Маша - так это моя жена", что тут блин еще расписывать

Comment: Слова в русском языке многозначные и многофункциональные: то что там, не подходит здесь. Меня интересует синтаксический анализ этого предложения.  Вот блин это и надо дополнить.

Comment: Да, тут надо и правда дополнять. Ну по крайней мере разобрались с ролью "это". Попозже добавлю разбор

Answer (score 2):

(1) ***Что** хорошо,  так это **то** (хорошо), что Солженицын перед Западом не пресмыкается.*

**Что** (подлежащее) хорошо (сказуемое), так это **то** (хорошо), что (союз) **Солженицын перед Западом не пресмыкается.**

Как вариант: ***так это то*** – обособленный (полупредикативный) оборот речи.

Вопрос-ответ построен на основе местоименной связи (что – так это) и изъяснительной связи.

(2) ***Кто** хорош, так это **Солженицын*** (хорош).

**Кто** (подлежащее) хорош (сказуемое), так это **Солженицын**.

Вопрос-ответ построен на основе местоименной связи (кто – так это).

**Как вариант**: Предложение **сложное** с местоименной связью. Второе предложение неполное, пропущено сказуемое «хорош». С другой стороны, неполное предложение можно считать обособленным оборотом речи.

**Примечания**

1. Источников по теме не нашлось, это версия самостоятельного разбора.
2. Интересно посмотреть, как строится фразеологизованная **модель** вопрос-ответного предложения.

Вопрос: ***Кто** хорош?* Ответ: ***Солженицын** хорош*.

Вопрос-ответ: ***Кто** хорош, так это **Солженицын** (хорош).*